# Multiple .get() calls in Firestore Security Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am developing the Firestore security rules for medical history app. I want staff and patients to be stored in separate collections to ensure HIPAA compliance (eg human resources or call center staff shouldn't be able to see clinical records). A patient belongs to a group which determines what products they have available to them. Patients shouldn't be able to see products from other groups. Staff need to have a privilege to see any products.

Data looks like this:

```
patient : {
    groupId: 1
}

product : {
    groupId: 1
}

staff: {
    canReadProducts: true
}
```

This rule works to allow a patient to read a product document:

```
match /products/{productId} {
    allow read: if get(.../patients/$(request.auth.uid))
                   .data.groupId == resource.data.groupId
}
```

This rule works to allow a staff member to read a product document:

```
match /products/{productId} {
    allow read: if get(.../staff/$(request.auth.uid))
                   .data.canReadProducts == true;
}
```

This rule does not work:

```
match /products/{productId} {
    allow read: if get(.../patients/$(request.auth.uid))
                   .data.groupId == resource.data.groupId
                || get(.../staff/$(request.auth.uid))
                   .data.canReadProducts == true;
}
```

*These are simplified for the sake of this question, I am testing that a user is authenticated and also using .exists() calls to check if documents exist. Read the "..." in the document paths to read "/database/$(databases)/documents".*

My questions is: How can I get multiple .get() calls to work in this senario?

Comment: Quick clarification of exactly what I am asking: How can I call more than one document other that the resource per rule. That seems to be the issue, I am testing against a products document (the resource) and a patient document and a staff document.

Answer (score 0):

I quite don't understand your question.
If you wanna know if all your `get` calls are gonna work, be sure they would. It's not a problem so far.

If you want to reduce your calls, for what you're doing you may declare a function to simplify your work.

Comment: My questions is: how do I get multiple .get() calls against different documents to work? Per my question, the first two rules work but the third does not. Functions are used to keep the code clean but do not reduce calls because a call against the document caches the document.